# Remote desktop lags/freezes for about 10 seconds when a message box or notification pops up

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, freeze, citrix, citrix-receiver

Why does my remote desktop connection lag/freeze for about 10 seconds when a message box or notification pops up? It only affects the actual remote session and I can minimize it and use my actual pc.

The remote desktop app is via citrix receiver.
Remote pc is Win10.
Client is Win10 and Win8.1.

Tried changing the following settings:

- Choose your connection speed to optimize performance
- Persistent bitmap caching

Thank you!

Comment: I've recently been getting the same. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I wasn't able to find a solution. I just moved to a different job that wouldn't require to use remote desktop so unfortunately I won't be of much help on this issue anymore. :/

Answer (score 1):

In my case, This is the issue about the audio settings.

Open Remote Desktop => Show Options => Local Resources tab => Remote audio => Settings

Select "Do not play" from Remote audio playback.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than ever.

My case involved the audio that accompanies the popup.

As soon as I disabled windows audio service from the remote PC lag/freezing was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is on the sound driver. I deleted the Sound drivers and added again. THe problem was solved. I expect when i do an driver update the problem is back again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).